# Rust `value borrowed here after move` when setting to Map

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I want to put an object in a serde_json::Map where the key will be a value from inside that object.

```rust
use serde_json::{json, Map, Value};

fn main() {
    let a = json!({
        "x": "y"
    });
    
    let mut d: Map<String, Value> = Map::new();
    d[&a["x"].to_string()] = a;
}
```

Error:

```
borrow of moved value: `a`
value borrowed here after moverustcE0382
main.rs(9, 30): value moved here
main.rs(4, 9): move occurs because `a` has type `Value`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if you solve this lifetime issue, the `IndexMut` implementation for `Map` cannot be used for inserting new elements into a map.  It panics if the given key is not present.

Use the `insert()` method instead, which solves both problems:

```
d.insert(a["x"].to_string(), a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the proper solution has already been answered, I am going to cover another perspective on this,

```rust
d[&a["x"].to_string()] = a;
```

Even if the mentioned bit panics when there is no entry against the passed index, what it is really saying is that, get me the value at index `x` and replace it with `a`, <strike>`=` is invoking `Copy` here, since `a` doesn't doesn't implement `Copy` trait the compiler is giving  you error.</strike>

In the following case, `a` is simply moved, so no `Copy` is invoked.

```rust
d.insert(a["x"].to_string(), a);
```

Also, the equivalent in your case may be get or insert.

```rust
let entry = d.entry(a["x"].to_string()).or_insert(a);
```

To access the value from entry you just deref it as `*entry`

Comment: No, the first case is not trying to invoke copying due to the use of the assignment operator. If you save `a["x"].to_string()` to a separate variable `key`, `d[&key] = a;` compiles and works (so long as the key is already present in the map).

Comment: Ah!!!, my bad, never mind, you are absolutely right!

Comment: Though the answer is based on incorrect analysis (strike-through part), I am keeping it here for the correct and relevant bits.